# gin web framework limit upload file size not working

Tags: go

i run the gin example about file upload , this repo is from https://github.com/gin-gonic/examples/tree/5898505356e9064c49abb075eae89596a3c5cd67/upload-file/single. 
when i change is limit

```
    router.MaxMultipartMemory = 1 // 8 MiB
```

but not woking for upload big file, anyone know this.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {

    router := gin.Default()
    // Set a lower memory limit for multipart forms (default is 32 MiB)
    router.MaxMultipartMemory = 1 // 8 MiB
    fmt.Println(router.MaxMultipartMemory)

    router.Static("/", "./public")
    router.POST("/upload", func(c *gin.Context) {
        ct := c.Request.Header.Get("Content-Type")
        fmt.Println(ct)
        name := c.PostForm("name")
        email := c.PostForm("email")
        // Source
        file, err := c.FormFile("file")
        if err != nil {
            c.String(http.StatusBadRequest, fmt.Sprintf("get form err: %s", err.Error()))
            return
        }

        if err := c.SaveUploadedFile(file, file.Filename); err != nil {
            c.String(http.StatusBadRequest, fmt.Sprintf("upload file err: %s", err.Error()))
            return
        }

        c.String(http.StatusOK, fmt.Sprintf("File %s uploaded successfully with fields name=%s and email=%s.", file.Filename, name, email))
    })
    router.Run(":8080")
}
```

i expect when file size bigger than limit ,there should be a error.

## update

misunderstand , the MaxMultipartMemory just limt the memory, not for file upload file size , even file size is more big than this , will write to temp file.

Comment: That doesn't set the max file size. It sets the max memory to be used in parsing multi-part requests. They are related, but not the same.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

as comment, code

```golang
  router.MaxMultipartMemory = 1 // 8 MiB
```

just limit program can use how much memory when upload file, not limit upload file size.

Comment: So this doesn't actually answers the question

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [MaxBytesReader](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#MaxBytesReader) can help?
The following should force the incoming request to be limited to 30MB

```golang
c.Request.Body = http.MaxBytesReader(c.Writer, c.Request.Body, int64(30<<20))
```